# Http input with authentication from angular app

Tags: angular, logstash

I use logstash+elasticsearch for logging staff from angular application. My logstash.conf is as follows:

```
input {
        http {
            response_headers => {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*"
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" => "*"
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" => "*"
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" => "*"
            }
            port => 5000
            user => "hi"
            password => "there"
        }
}

output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        }
}
```

At first I didn't have user/password and worked nicely when I was posting data from angular 5:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
this.httpClient.
        post<any>('http://myhost/logstash', {message: 'test'}, { headers: headers, responseType: 'text'  as 'json' })
        .subscribe(
          data => console.log(data),
          error => console.log(error));
```

where headers was:

When I added the user/password POSTing to logstash stopped. I added:

```
headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('hi:there'));
```

but while headers are appended, OPTIONS http request to logstash doesn't have the Authorization value so it fails with 401. It seems though I can send an OPTIONS/POST command from postman.
I cannot find where the problem lies. Is it on angular headers? Or logstash configuration?

Comment: I'd say it's in your logstash configuration. I don't think browser send Authorization headers in preflight requests

Comment: but postman can send a post/options command to logstash

Comment: you can send an OPTIONS request via postman, **without** specifying the Authorization header?

Comment: no I can not. If I send OPTIONS without authorization header, I get an empty response. If I set Authorization header, I get ok.

Comment: empty response with 401 http code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that angular HttpClient automatically performs an OPTIONS http request where it omits the headers. 
So is there a way to enforce httpClient to use the header with Authorization token?